# click() event not working. scripts conflicting with each other

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, conflict

I am using jquery-1.10.2 and bootstrap for my project.To develop an autocomplete module I included jquery-ui-1.8.10.custom.min.js and jquery-1.4.4.min.js.

After that, forms which are being submitted by using jquery, are not working.The click() event is not working for any of the forms.

Are these scripts conflicting with each other?

Please tell me how to recover from this. I am baffled.

Comment: It is highly recommended to NOT include 2 different versions of jQuery (1.4.4 and 1.10.2, in your case) on the same page.

Comment: Don't include two separate versions of jQuery.

Comment: @MattBurland I have checked it by deleting jquery-1.4.4 but in that scenario  my auto-suggestion is not working

Comment: @Adam  I have checked it by deleting jquery-1.4.4 but in that scenario my auto-suggestion is not working

Answer (score 0):

You should only be using one version of jQuery not two.

For example, you can do this:

jQuery v1.10.2

Bootstrap v3.0.3 (works with jQuery v1.10.2)

jQuery UI v1.10.3 (works with jQuery v1.10.2)

Comment: I should also add that you need to be judicious re what you use from jQuery UI as there are potentials for conflicts between Bootstrap and UI. e.g. Both styling h3 tags.

Comment: Also, if you're just using jQuery UI for a type-ahead, there are a couple of solutions for Bootstrap 3 out there. e.g. https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js (which per http://bootply.com/101417 is for Bootstrap 3.) Examples: http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/

Comment: I was not prepared for this. I wrote my own auto-suggest script.but somehow key events are not working for that .. can look into that code and tell me where am I doing it wrong ??

Comment: You may want to include your own auto-complete code, (a new question?) which you haven't included here. Without that, it isn't really possible for people to be more specific with suggestions on what you may be doing incorrectly. A runnable implementation using it would be useful (such as on JS Fiddle.) However, I'd be more inclined to adopt an existing off-the-shelf auto-complete. There are many out there for jQuery that would work with any UI framework (Bootstrap etc.) Why re-invent the wheel?